# PagedList with large data sets

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I'm using X.PagedList for paging functionality in my application.  The code I have works fine but when I return larger sets of data it seems like it could be faster.  Is there anything I can do to my code to have it perform more efficiently?

Controller Code

```
var employees = _service.GetEmployeesByOffice(region, area, office).OrderBy(e => e.FullName);
var model = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Employee>,IEnumerable<EmployeesViewModel>>(employees).ToPagedList(page, 20);

var viewModel = new EmployeeListingView
{
    EmployeeViewModel = model,
    // Additional...
};

return View(viewModel);
```

Service Call

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesByOffice(string region, string area, string office)
{
    var query = _context.Employees.AsQueryable();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(region))
        query = query.Where(e => e.Region == region);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(area))
        query = query.Where(e => e.Area == area);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(office))
        query = query.Where(e => e.Office == office);

    return query;
}
```

Razor Page

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.EmployeeViewModel, page => Url.Action("Index", new { area = Model.SelectedArea, office = Model.SelectedOffice, page }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the issue was with the mapping.  Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12463289/5904879), I created an extension to handle mapping the object after calling it.  I changed this code

> ```
> var employees = 
>       _service
>           .GetEmployeesByOffice(region, area, office)
>           .OrderBy(e => e.FullName);
> var model = 
>       Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Employee>, IEnumerable<EmployeesViewModel>>(employees)
>       .ToPagedList(page, 20);
> ```

to this

```
var model = 
    _service
        .GetEmployeesByOffice(region, sArea, sOffice)
        .OrderBy(e => e.FullName)
        .ToPagedList(page, 20)
        .ToMappedPagedList<Employee, EmployeesViewModel>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say anything about the mapping but you can simplify this query

> ```
> public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesByOffice(string region, string area, string office)
> {
>     var query = _context.Employees.AsQueryable();
>
>     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(region))
>         query = query.Where(e => e.Region == region);
>
>     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(area))
>         query = query.Where(e => e.Area == area);
>
>     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(office))
>         query = query.Where(e => e.Office == office);
>
>     return query;
> }
> ```

into this one. Each expression will resove either to `true` or the actual condition if the variable was provided.

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesByOffice(string region, string area, string office)
{
    return
        from e in _context.Employees.AsQueryable()
        where
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(region) || e.Region == region) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(area) || e.Area == area) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(office) || e.Office == office);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I figured there was a way to simplify this but wasn't sure.